# How big is the Lorentz force on the Sun?

Tags: the-sun, earth, milky-way, magnetic-field

The [LOFAR](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article-abstract/484/3/3646/5301409?redirectedFrom=fulltext) observations have made an estimate of the magnetic field of the Milky Way. The value in our region is very small. About 1/1000 of the Earth magnetic field.

The Earth and the Sun move at a cosiderable speed around the center of the Milky Way though. Both move with a speed of around 828 000 km/hr around the center of the Milky Way.

Now currents moving in a magnetic field experience a Lorentz force:

$$F_{l}=-qv\times B$$

Where $q$ is the charge, $v$ the speed of the charge, and $B$ the magnetic field the charges move in. The force is always perpendicular to the velocity.

Now on the Sun, as well as inside the Earth, there is a net current giving rise to their magnetic fields. This means there is a net current in the direction of motion around our galaxy.

How big would be the force on the Sun moving through the magnetic field of the Milky Way?

Comment: "This means there is a net current in the direction of motion around our galaxy." I don't follow this logic.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/651722/2451

Answer (score 4):

Due to the fact that electrons can escape the gravitational field of the sun more easily than ions, the sun is positively charged by an amount $q=77$ Coulombs (see https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/abs/2001/24/aah2649/aah2649.html ). You can calculate the Lorentz force from this. The magnetic field of the Milky Way is however even much smaller than 1/1000 of the earth's (not sure where you go this figure from). According to this reference http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Galactic_magnetic_fields#Magnetic_Fields_in_the_Milky_Way , the galactic magnetic field near the sun is about $6\mu G =6\times 10^{-6}G$. With this the Lorentz force on the sun comes out as about $110 N$. For comparison, the gravitational force on the sun by the galaxy amounts to about $4\times10^{20} N$ (see [How strong is the force between the Sun and the centre of the Milky Way?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18866/how-strong-is-the-force-between-the-sun-and-the-centre-of-the-milky-way) ).

The fact that there are electric currents in the sun doesn't make any difference here. It is only a non-zero net charge that can create a Lorentz force on the sun as a whole.

Comment: Oh *this is great!* You are most welcome to post an answer to [What are the experimental limits to the residual charge of the Sun?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23319/7982) along the lines "It is not likely to be measurable since predictions put it at only..." Quote a few lines from the paper, such as the paragraph beginning "We can demonstrate that the existence of the global charge is necessary to avoid some serious physical problems." etc.

Comment: @uhoh I added an answer to that other question, using my own arguments though (the one in the referenced paper, although giving the correct result, contains one or two slightly hand-waving arguments in the derivation)

Comment: I see that now and I love it; thank you very much!